# ACF : delete a field nested inside a group

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to programatically delete an image sub field of a Group field element in ACF.
Group field name is `img_gallery` and the image field inside it that needs to be deleted is `img2`. These 2 codes is what I have tried separately but to no avail. No error is thrown, yet no effect is taking place.

```
delete_sub_field(array('img_gallery', 1, 'img2'), 314);

delete_field('img2', 314);
```

*Group field -> Image Field*